# ExpressJS / NodeJS Redirect Image

Tags: html, node.js, redirect, express

Is it okay for an `img` to have src value with redirect to another page?

In view, I have `img`:

```
<img src='/images/fileName'/>
```

In app.js

```
app.get('/images/:fileName', subject.image);
```

This is my route:

```
exports.image = function(req, res){
    var fileName = req.fileName;
    fs.exists(fileName, function(exists){
        if (exists) {
            res.sendfile(imagePath);
        }else{
            res.redirect('http://gravatar.com/avatar/_some_hash');
        }
    });
}
```

My code works, but is it okay to use `res.redirect` if image does not exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's ok to redirect.  In the end its just a GET to the HTTP server and the browser will follow the redirect.

As mentioned in this question: ([Is it OK to HTTP redirect images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778347/is-it-ok-to-http-redirect-images)) you might not want do to that for lots of images.

Answer (score 0):

Also You may set default image:

```
<img src="/images/fileName" onerror="this.src='/images/default.png'" />
```