# How do I implement redirect image using Express?

Tags: node.js, redirect, express

I want to make GET request to my nodejs server.

I want to implement redirecting image.
On client I have

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var childElement = document.createElement('img');
childElement.width = 1;
childElement.height = 1;
childElement.style.daiplay = 'none';
childElement.src = 'http://myendpoint.com/api/endpoint?token=token';
body.appendChild(childElement);
```

My endpoint should redirect client to some URL.

in server code I have

```
app.route('/api/endpoint').get(function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('http://google.com')
});
```

As a result I get

**General**

```
Request URL:http://myurl.com
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:1340
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
Location: http://google.com
Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 41
Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 10:50:13 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

But client is not actually redirected.. 
After this request GET to redirect page happens, but I receive html in response, not being redirected..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the intended behaviour? that the user is redirected after clicking the image?

Comment: @AshleyB, thank you for reply. 
No, When image is appended to document, the get request is sent to link in src attribute of image, then server redirects user

Comment: All your doing is redirecting the request for the image to the new domain. In other words, you're redirecting the browser, not the user. You can't change the current pages 'page' just with an image, not without some on-click event style behaviour. I

Comment: @AshleyB please, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966255/expressjs-nodejs-redirect-image?rq=1)

This guy doing something very similar.. and it works for him...

Comment: Are you sure that your response is actually an image? sounds like you're setting the source to a non-image page

Comment: so, i should do something like this:

`res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/gif');
res.send(image);
res.redirect('google.com')`;

Comment: It depends on the redirected site to set those, e.g google.com