# rack-rewrite - rails3.2 - heroku - redirect hardcoded image urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, heroku, rack-rewrite

My images were all held in the app itself and so were referenced with /images/12345.jpg which in some places has been hard coded into the content of the cms, with or without the full url.

The images have now been moved to s3 and so I want to add a redirect for urls that are of the following formats:
/images/12345.jpg|png|gif
or
http://www.example.com/images/12345.jpg|png|gif
(but only for only numeric filenames)

and point them to

```
http://my.images.images.s3.amazonaws.com/540x310/12345.jpg|png|gif
```

I currently have

```
use Rack::Rewrite do
rewrite %r{images\/(\d*.)(jpe?g|png|gif)$}, 'http://my.images.images.s3.amazonaws.com/540x310/$1$2'
end
```

But this doesn't seem quite right.

UPDATE------
of course the URL in the source doesn't change, I should have realised that. Clicking the link directly returns an error:

No route matches [GET] "/http://my.images.images.s3.amazonaws.com/540x310/13135.jpeg"

(note the leading slash)

So the rewrite is working but it thinks it should be routing to an internal link not an external URL.

UPDATE2------
Changing to

```
r302 %r{(?:images\/)(\d*.jpe?g|png|gif)$}, "http://my.images.images.s3.amazonaws.com/540x310/$1"
```

will now redirect if I go to 
http://www.example.com/images/13135.jpeg

but is not rendering the images in the site itself.

Comment: "But this doesn't seem quite right" what does that mean? Are you getting errors or what?

Comment: no error messages, no redirect, nada. the regex is correct i'm pretty sure.

Comment: made a slight correction to the regex,but still not matching... (?:images\/)(\d*.jpe?g|png|gif)$

Comment: test your redirects with curl like `curl -I "http://localhost:5000/images/12345.jpg"`

Comment: with rewrite i HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
with r302 i HTTP/1.1 302 Found with the redirected location

Comment: yeah, rewrite won't work with a foreign host. redirect should work though.

Comment: so a 302 as dexcribed shoul be showing the images correctly inline? The old URL is showing in the source but if i load that in a new broswer it does the right thing. Not sure how i can get the images to display properly? Any ideas?

Comment: i think so and SO also says so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778347/is-it-ok-to-http-redirect-images

Comment: another thing you can do is serve the images from your rails app by fetching it from the remote and caching them on disc or something like that.

Comment: the r302 is redirecting fine with curl but looking at the network tab in chrome and firefox i'm getting 404 Not Found. Any idea why the browser would ignore it?

Comment: sure that it redirects to the right file? did you try opening the original url in the browser?

Comment: yes, if i put the original path in my browser it redirects to the new location. localhost:3000/images/13135.jpeg   >>   http://my.images.s3.amazonaws.com/540x310/13135.jpeg

Comment: this was caused by the url on the localhost still pointing to the live url and therefore the 301 rewrite never being called. fixed now. thanks for your help phoet

Answer (score 2):

this was caused by the url on the localhost still pointing to the live url and therefore the 301 rewrite never being called.

So the local deployment had the live URL hardcoded into the page, i was then changing this and pointing my browser at localhost.

In the page though the old URL remained which meant the page was looking to the live server for a possible redirect which had never been dpeloyed