# Is it OK to HTTP redirect images used in email clients?

Tags: http-status-code-301, email-client, http-status-code-302

I have seen the answers to [Is it OK to HTTP redirect images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778347/is-it-ok-to-http-redirect-images). It is a YES - browsers would follow redirection.

However, do email clients (GMail, Express, Thunderbird, Yahoo...) follow the same rule?

Answer (score 3):

I just answered this at [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1261806/788225). Here is the same answer:

Yes. I just sent an email containing `<img src="http://www.example.com/img/logo.png" alt="not displayed"/>`. The example server is in my control in redirects to the same URL with https.

My findings:

- GMail on 24 Oct 2017: It displays the image, but replaces it's location to something like `https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2ks...5hk=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.example.com/img/logo.png`. I guess that all browsers follow redirects and therefore all webmail interfaces should be fine.
- Thunderbird 52.4.0: It doesn't load remote content by default, but after allowing it, the image gets displayed correctly.
- Evolution 3.18.5.2: Same as Thunderbird. Once you load images via Ctrl+I, it's displayed.
- Outlook (unknown version): A colleague confirmed that it's displaying on their Windows machine.
- Mail on macOS (10.3): Another colleague confirmed that it's displaying when they re-open the email. It might just be that the image took a few seconds to load, not sure.