# 302 image redirects slower in browsers

Tags: php, html, image, redirect, browser

I am on a WAMP stack and have the below one line of code for `demo.html`

```
<img src="http://localhost/redirect/demo.php"></img>
```

`demo.php` code as below

```
<?php
header("Location: http://localhost/redirect/blah");
exit();
?>
```

The code works fine. but there is huge response time **during content download**
[image: Response time using IMG tag]

when I change `demo.html` to use script tag vs img tag, there are **no problems** during response times

```
<script src="http://localhost/redirect/demo.php"></script>
```

[image: Response time using SCRIPT tag]

Not sure why this is happening to IMG tags. Could anyone explain why this is happening and how do I avoid this? Are there any alternate methods to loading IMG via 302 without a javascript solution.

Note - believe this cannot be a PHP/WAMP problem as the response times are not affected when I call **`http://localhost/redirect/demo.php`** directly. Trust this has something to do with browser, its rendering, its load events.

Comment: The modern browsers are smarter in the case of scripts.. they will load scripts simultaneously. At the same time, HTML will load in a top down approach and img tags will be shown after the image is fetched. And @Vivek is right, scripts are loaded synchronously whereas images are queued and loaded asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, scripts are loaded synchronously whereas images are queued and loaded asynchronously.

So my understanding is if you use **script** tag, browsers wait to load `http://localhost/redirect/demo.php` which sends 302. This forces browser to execute `http://localhost/redirect/blah` before loading anything else.

Instead if you use **img** tag, browsers execute `http://localhost/redirect/demo.php` and continue to load remaining portion of the page. When demo.php returns 302, `http://localhost/redirect/blah` gets added to the queue of URLs to be loaded. Because of which the overall time to load the image is more.

Not sure if you can avoid it. Probably, enabling caching on demo.php could help in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the usage of your image redirect, you can take a look at [URL Rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

I'm not sure it's a good solution because your example code is out of context.

You can also take a look at this question which can provide you additional informations : [Is it OK to HTTP redirect images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778347/is-it-ok-to-http-redirect-images)

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^redirect/demo.php$ /redirect/blah [QSA,L]
```

Eventualy if you want to have the "blah" file/script on the other server you can use Reverse Proxy see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension